# Multiple PWAs on the same host but different ports - same origin behavior

Tags: progressive-web-apps, same-origin-policy, sap-fiori

We´re transforming a SAP Fiori launchpad into a PWA by loading a manifest and a service worker from a custom endpoint. The actual server (SAP Gateway) is composed of multiple clients (~tenants) and we use a web dispatcher (reverse proxy) that allows users to access client specific launchpads by mapping HTTPS ports to gateway clients. Applications vary between clients.

Goal: Provide separate PWA installations for each gateway client.

Issue: **Chrome on Android** ignores the port when checking whether a PWA for the current page is already installed (same origin-domain).

Example:

| Instance | Client | Host | Page URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEV | 100 | dev.company.com:**11**443 | /sap/bc/.../FioriLaunchpad.html |
| DEV | 200 | dev.company.com:**21**443 | /sap/bc/.../FioriLaunchpad.html |

Lets say we install the launchpad PWA for *dev.company.com:**11**443* (client 100) and then access the *dev.company.com:**21**443* (client 200) launchpad using Chrome on Android. Chrome considers that page to be installed as there is a PWA registered for *dev.company.com:/sap/bc/.../FioriLaunchpad.html* although the port and therefore the origin of the client 200 page differs. Thus, there is no way to install a separate PWA for client 200.

From my understanding PWAs should be (somehow) [origin dependent](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#same-origin). What am I missing? Is there any way to enforce some kind of same-origin behavior? This works fine using Chrome on Windows btw.